# multiple definition c++/c google test

Tags: c++, googletest

So ive looked at similar issues and I followed what they said. I have made sure that my .h and .cpp file are in my main test file.

So I'm not really sure whats wrong. I fixed an earlier error like this but it was something I caught. Id appreciate some help.

Matrix-Multiply.h

```
Matrix-Multiply.h
#ifndef __MATRIX_MULTIPLY_H
#define __MATRIX_MULTIPLY_H  

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


float *expectedFinalMatrixOutput(int mA,int nA,int mB,int nB,float *matA,float *matB);

int readFiles(const char *matAFile,const char *matBFile);


#endif //__MATRIX_MULTIPLY_H
```

Matrix-Multiply.cpp

```
//.cpp file
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float *expectedFinalMatrixOutput(int mA,int nA,int mB,int nB,float *matA,float *matB)
{
    int m = mA;
    int n = nB;
    int size = m * n;
    float *finalMatrix[size];
    //build both matrices
    //for both the matA Column and matB Row need to be the 
    //same before even multiplying
    //dot product matrix
    //the end matrix needs the have the same number of rows as 
    //matA and same number of columns as matB
    return *finalMatrix;
}

int readFiles(const char *matAFile,const char *matBFile)
{
    int flag;
    //read in file for matrixs
    //set flag for whether true or false
    //verify row and column being taken have actual values and 
    //that the sized are correct
    return flag;
}
```

Matrix-Multiply_unittests.cpp

```
// tests.cpp

#include "Matrix-Multiply.h"
#include "Matrix-Multiply.cpp"
#include<gtest/gtest.h>
#include<stdio.h>

TEST(matrixSize,emptyMatrix)
{
    float *matA = NULL;
    float *matB = NULL;
    float *matrix = 
    expectedFinalMatrixOutput(0,0,0,0,matA,matB);
    ASSERT_EQ(*(matrix),0);
}

TEST(dotTest,oneByoneMatrix) 
{
    float fMatrix[1] = {1};
    float sMatrix[1] = {1};
    float *matrix = expectedFinalMatrixOutput(1,1,1,1,fMatrix,sMatrix);
    ASSERT_EQ(matrix[0],1);
}

TEST(dotTest,twoBytwoMatrix)
{
    float fMatrix[4] = {1,1,1,1};
    float sMatrix[4] = {1,1,1,1};
    float *matrix = expectedFinalMatrixOutput(2,2,2,2,fMatrix,sMatrix);
    for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {
            EXPECT_EQ(2,matrix[i]);
    }
}

TEST(ReadFilesTest,filesExist)
{
    const char *matA = "../src/Matrix1_3_3.txt";
    const char *matB = "../src/Matrix2_3_3.txt";
    ASSERT_EQ(0,readFiles(matA,matB));
}

TEST(ReadFilesTest,filesDontExist)
{
    const char *matA = "../src/notReal.txt";
    const char *matB = "../src/Matrix2_3_3.txt";
    ASSERT_EQ(0,readFiles(matA,matB));
}

TEST(ReadFilesTest,matrixSizeNotCompatible)
{
    const char *matA = "../src/Matrix1_3_3.txt";
    const char *matB = "../src/Matrix2_2_2.txt";
    ASSERT_EQ(0,readFiles(matA,matB));
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

Sorry if its not all on one line. I tried to get it that way. But the error i get is:

```
obj/Matrix-Multiply.o: In function `expectedFinalMatrixOutput(int, int, int, 
int, float*, float*)':
Matrix-Multiply.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 
`expectedFinalMatrixOutput(int, int, int, int, float*, float*)'
/tmp/ccUgZRUB.o:Matrix-Multiply_unittests.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined 
here
obj/Matrix-Multiply.o: In function `readFiles(char const*, char const*)':
Matrix-Multiply.cpp:(.text+0xbe): multiple definition of `readFiles(char 
const*, char const*)'
/tmp/ccUgZRUB.o:Matrix-Multiply_unittests.cpp:(.text+0xbe): first defined 
here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Im using googletest and already make a call to make gtest
However this error occurs when i call make test.

Any help is appreciated

Makefile

```
CPP=g++
OBJ=obj
SRC=src
BIN=bin
CPPFLAGS=-I$(SRC)
GTEST_DIR=../googletest/googletest

gtest:
    mkdir -p $(OBJ)
    ${CPP} -I${GTEST_DIR}/include -I${GTEST_DIR} \
    -pthread -c ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-all.cc -o $(OBJ)/gtest-all.o
    ar -rv $(OBJ)/libgtest.a $(OBJ)/gtest-all.o

GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I${GTEST_DIR}/include -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c 
\
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc -o $@

$(OBJ)/gtest_main.a : $(OBJ)/gtest-all.o $(OBJ)/gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: test clean

test:  $(OBJ)/Matrix-Multiply.o $(OBJ)/gtest_main.a
    mkdir -p $(BIN)
    $(CPP) -I${GTEST_DIR}/include $(SRC)/Matrix-Multiply_unittests.cpp \
            $(OBJ)/gtest_main.a $(OBJ)/Matrix-Multiply.o -o $(BIN)/Matrix- 
Multiply_unittests -pthread
    $(BIN)/Matrix-Multiply_unittests

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)/*
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*
```

Comment: `#include "Matrix-Multiply.cpp"` is your problem. Never include a .cpp file.

Comment: Post your actual error messages formatted as a code block, they are unreadable otherwise.

Comment: its been a while since ive done make files and should the header just include the .cpp file instead?

Comment: edited the error code to block format. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your makefile is also broken. You are compiling `$(SRC)/Matrix-Multiply_unittests.cpp` but it's not a dependency of anything. Build a proper dependency graph.

Comment: Alright ill try and get with some class mates who have more knowledge about it to help me understand it. I wouldn't doubt if that was the issue. But some how it worked for another class mate though maybe he edited it.

Comment: @RutgerLuther It's simple. Never include a cpp file, not in another cpp file, not in a header file. The point of cpp files is to be compiled, the point of header files is to be included. Not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I can remember that simple rule

Answer (score 0):

I think by `#include "Matrix-Multiply.cpp"` you are including the functions once.

Also (although not shown), you are linking with Matrix-Multiply on the link line.

You should not normally include a `.cpp` file.  They are better bound by linking the file.

```
g++ -o my_awesome_app main.o Matrix-Multiply.o otherfile.o
```

Comment: So i tried it. But it didnt help. I also try just using it in the other files and toying around with it a bit more. Thought that only made things worse sadly haha. Ill post the makefile as well.